# use a ternary within a map function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get my toggle button to work, however I am getting an error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression at the start of calling the isToggled function. Not to sure why this is not working?

```
    {regressionTestsData.map(test =>
      {isToggled ?   <div key={test.id} className='Table RegressionTestsGrid' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => onRegressionTestClick(test.id)}>
      <div>{test.id}</div>
      <div>
        {`${typeof(test.request_by) === 'string' ? test.request_by : test.request_by.full_name} (${formatUTCDateToCurrentDateWithoutSeconds(test.request_timestamp)})`}
      </div>
      <Tooltip title={test.project_name}>
        <div className='HideExtraText' style={{margin: '0'}}>{test.project_name}</div>      
      </Tooltip>
      <Tooltip title={test.database}>
        <div>{getPartialDatabase(test.database)}</div>
      </Tooltip>
      <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_errors}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_not_applicable}</div>
         <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_count}</div>
         <div>{getIcon(test.regression_test_summary)}</div>
      </div>
      
      :
      <div>
      <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
      <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
   </div>

      }
```

Comment: Either user `return` keyword just before `isToggled` or remove `{}` which is used to wrapped ternary statement

Comment: You're not returning anything from map() inner code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {regressionTestsData.map(test =>
//add return here
  {return isToggled ?   <div key={test.id} className='Table RegressionTestsGrid' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => onRegressionTestClick(test.id)}>
  <div>{test.id}</div>
  <div>
    {`${typeof(test.request_by) === 'string' ? test.request_by : test.request_by.full_name} (${formatUTCDateToCurrentDateWithoutSeconds(test.request_timestamp)})`}
  </div>
  <Tooltip title={test.project_name}>
    <div className='HideExtraText' style={{margin: '0'}}>{test.project_name}</div>      
  </Tooltip>
  <Tooltip title={test.database}>
    <div>{getPartialDatabase(test.database)}</div>
  </Tooltip>
  <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_errors}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_not_applicable}</div>
     <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_count}</div>
     <div>{getIcon(test.regression_test_summary)}</div>
  </div>
  
  :
  <div>
  <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_passes}</div>
  <div>{test.regression_test_summary.unit_test_fails}</div>
 </div>

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `return` keyword before `isToggled`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the curly brace will do the needful.